# Add Content with a sharepoint webserver with in sharepoint farm where we have more than 1 webfrontend server

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

We have a sharepoint farm (with three web front end server and these server maange by a loadbalancer) we can access our sharepoint portal via two way one is using loadbalancer url and second directry type the perticuler server url, my question is if any user directry type the url for any server with in a farm and add the conetnt in that case is there any chanace that data will not be visiable to other users with in the same farm.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only thing to look out for is links they add, make sure these don't contain the server url instead of the real url, as this will bypass the redundancy you got by adding multiple servers and of cause fail if the server is removed. Note that often these links will be inside documents and emails and also in systems outside SharePoint. So using the "wrong" urls is bad practice.

Another thing to keep in mind is that this will only work for the web application which is configured with port 80 and no host header. Which also gives you a way of preventing the "wrong" urls from working.